# how to $_POST form attributes to another file

Tags: php

[This is the thank you page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OD9c.png)  I am trying to have someones name be displayed like "Thank you John, ..."
But i can't seem to have it post the name. my $first_name is in another php file

```html
<?php include("email.php"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<base target="_blank">
<title>Mid-Night Designs</title>
<style type="text/css">

body *{font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif !important}

div, p, a, li, td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }

*{-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;}
td{word-break: break-word;}
a{word-break: break-word; text-decoration: none; color: inherit;}

body .ReadMsgBody
{width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
body .ExternalClass
{width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
body{width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #ffffff; margin:0; padding:0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}
html{ background-color:#ffffff; width: 100%;}

body p {padding: 0!important; margin-top: 0!important; margin-right: 0!important; margin-bottom: 0!important; margin-left: 0!important; }
body img {user-drag: none; -moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none;}
body a.rotator img {-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; }
body a.rotator img:hover {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); -o-transform: rotate(360deg);-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }
body .hover:hover {opacity:0.85;filter:alpha(opacity=85);}
body .jump:hover {opacity:0.75; filter:alpha(opacity=75); padding-top: 10px!important;}

body .logo img {width: 150px; height: auto;}
body .icon25 img {width: 25px; height: auto;}
body .icon18 img {width: 18px; height: auto;}

</style>

<style type="text/css">@media only screen and (max-width: 640px){
  body body{width:auto!important;}
  body table[class=full] {width: 100%!important; clear: both; }
  body table[class=mobile] {width: 100%!important; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px; clear: both; }
  body table[class=fullCenter] {width: 100%!important; text-align: center!important; clear: both; }
  body td[class=fullCenter] {width: 100%!important; text-align: center!important; clear: both; }
  body .erase {display: none;}
  body .buttonScale {float: none!important; text-align: center!important; display: inline-block!important; clear: both;}
  body td[class=pad20] {padding-left: 20px!important; padding-right: 20px!important; text-align: center!important; clear: both; }

}</style>

<style type="text/css">@media only screen and (max-width: 479px){ 
  body body{width:auto!important;}
  body table[class=full] {width: 100%!important; clear: both; }
  body table[class=mobile] {width: 100%!important; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; clear: both; }
  body table[class=fullCenter] {width: 100%!important; text-align: center!important; clear: both; }
  body td[class=fullCenter] {width: 100%!important; text-align: center!important; clear: both; }
  body .erase {display: none;}
  body .buttonScale {float: none!important; text-align: center!important; display: inline-block!important; clear: both;}
  body td[class=pad20] {padding-left: 20px!important; padding-right: 20px!important; text-align: center!important; clear: both; }
  

}</style>

</head>

<body style='margin: 0; padding: 0;'>



<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="full" bgcolor="#1e1e1e" style="background-color: #1e1e1e;">
 <tbody><tr>
  <td align="center">
  
   <table class="full" align="center" border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody><tr>
     <td align="center" class="pad20">
     
      <table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="full">
       <tbody><tr>
        <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td valign="middle" width="100%" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; color: #929292; font-weight: 400; font-size: 12px; line-height: 20px; text-align: center;">
         <br>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="40" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="center" width="100%" class="logo" style="line-height: 1px; text-align: center;"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="30" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody></table>
      
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table>
   
  </td>
 </tr>
</table><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="full" bgcolor="#1e1e1e" style="background-color: #1e1e1e;">
 <tbody><tr>
  <td align="center" class="pad20">
  
   <table class="full" align="center" border="0" width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="background-color: #ffffff; border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px;">
    <tbody><tr>
     <td width="100%" height="30" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table>
   
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="full" bgcolor="#1e1e1e" style="background-color: #1e1e1e;">
 <tbody><tr>
  <td align="center" class="pad20">
  
   <table class="full" align="center" border="0" width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
    <tbody><tr>
     <td align="center" class="pad20">
     
      <table width="450" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="full">
       <tbody><tr>
        <td width="100%" height="10" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td valign="middle" width="100%" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; color: #111111; font-weight: 800; font-size: 30px; line-height: 36px; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase;">
         Thank you!
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="20" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td width="100%" style="color: #929292; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-weight: 400; vertical-align: top; font-size: 14px; text-align: center; line-height: 22px;" class="fullCenter">
         <span style="color:#000000;"><span style="font-size:14px;"><strong>Thank you<?php echo $_POST['first_name'];?>
, for using our quote calculator. If you have any further questions feel free to contact us!</strong></span></span>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="20" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody></table>
      
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table>
   
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>















<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="full" bgcolor="#1e1e1e" style="background-color: #1e1e1e;">
 <tbody><tr>
  <td align="center" class="pad20">
  
   <table class="full" align="center" border="0" width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
    <tbody><tr>
     <td width="100%" height="30" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="center" class="pad20">
           
      <table width="450" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="full">
       <tbody><tr>
        <td valign="top" width="100%">
        
         <table width="75" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter">
          <tbody><tr>
           <td valign="middle" align="center" width="30" class="fullCenter" style="line-height: 1px;"></td>
          </tr>
         </tbody></table>
         
         <table width="15" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="full">
          <tbody><tr>
           <td width="100%" height="10" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
         </tbody></table>
         
         <table width="350" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullCenter">
          <tbody><tr>
           <td width="100%" style="color: #111111; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-weight: 700; vertical-align: top; font-size: 13px; text-align: left; line-height: 24px;" class="fullCenter">
            Lorenzo Preciado
           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td width="100%" style="color: #61b94d; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-weight: 600; vertical-align: top; font-size: 13px; text-align: left; line-height: 24px text-transform: uppercase;" class="fullCenter">
            <span style="color:#000000;">Web Designer &amp; Developer&nbsp;</span>
           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td width="100%" style="color: #929292; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-weight: 400; vertical-align: top; font-size: 13px; text-align: left; line-height: 24px;" class="fullCenter">
            Owner of Mid-Night Designs
           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td width="100%" style="color: #929292; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-weight: 400; vertical-align: top; font-size: 13px; text-align: left; line-height: 24px;" class="fullCenter">
            +81 080-6499-4974 &nbsp; |&nbsp;&nbsp; <a  href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #929292;">h</a>elp@mid-nightdesigns.com
           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td width="100%" height="5" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td width="100%" align="center" class="icon18">
           
            <!-- Social Icons -->
            <table width="120" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="buttonScale">
             <tbody><tr>
              <td valign="middle" align="left" width="30" class="buttonScale" style="line-height: 1px;"></td>
              <td valign="middle" align="left" width="30" class="buttonScale" style="line-height: 1px;"></td>
              <td valign="middle" align="left" width="30" class="buttonScale" style="line-height: 1px;"></td>
              <td valign="middle" align="left" width="30" class="buttonScale" style="line-height: 1px;"></td>
             </tr>
            </tbody></table>
            
           </td>
          </tr>
         </tbody></table>
         
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="10" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody></table>
      
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table>
   
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="full" bgcolor="#1e1e1e" style="background-color: #1e1e1e;">
 <tbody><tr>
  <td align="center" class="pad20">
  
   <table class="full" align="center" border="0" width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="background-color: #ffffff; border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;">
    <tbody><tr>
     <td width="100%" height="30" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table>
   
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="full" bgcolor="#1e1e1e" style="background-color: #1e1e1e;">
 <tbody><tr>
  <td width="100%" valign="top" align="center">
   
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="mobile">
    <tbody><tr>
     <td align="center">
      
      <table width="450" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; text-align: center;" class="fullCenter">
       <tbody><tr>
        <td width="100%" height="30" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td width="100%" style="color: #d2d2d2; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-weight: 400; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px; text-align: center; line-height: 24px;" class="fullCenter">
         © Copyright - <a  href="http://mid-nightdesigns.com" style="text-decoration: none;">Mid-Nightd<span style="color:#FFFFFF;"></span>esigns.com</a>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td width="100%" style="color: #61b94d; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; font-weight: 400; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px; text-align: center; line-height: 24px;" class="fullCenter">
         <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #61b94d;"><br></a>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="50" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="1" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody></table>
      
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table>
  
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the portion of the form

```html
 <label>
                First Name   
                <input NAME="first_name" type="text" required="required" class="SV_validate" placeholder="First Name">
              </label>
```

This is part of my email.php and it works, displaying the name in the email sent but doesn't work in the thank you.

```html
 $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
```

Comment: <?php echo $_POST['first_name'];?>

Comment: You should look at session variables.

Comment: what Matt said is correct you should use session variables

Comment: How does the form look like?

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan That didn't work

Comment: @Matt I don't know what that is.. Kinda new to php

Comment: Post more code as this info is not enough.

Comment: I think it's better for you to show us your code in **both** php files

Comment: I have added more code

Comment: If it displays the name in the email sent but don't show up in the thankyou-part it's obvious that the name is sent from the form to the server. You still have to supply more code so it's possible to understand where the issue is. How does the thankyou-part-code look like?

Comment: I assume that you have a form on a page, submitting it with firstname and it appears in email file and then you are redirecting user to thank you page. You have more than one redirection, so you need to carry forward submitted value.. You can use either session/cookie or if you have form on email page then set hidden input.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld, read `Kinda new to php`

Comment: @Kamal That is exactly what is going on, however i don't know how to incorporate Sessions

Answer (score 0):

PHP File that receives POST will be somewthing along the lines of

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['Name'] = $_POST['first_name'];

?>
```

Second File will be

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['Name'];
?>
```

Not recommended to do exactly that but that's the basis. You also can't set a session on the same page and call it on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the simple scenario created for you, change the form action to thank-you.php file.

index.php

```
<form action="thank-you.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" name="contact" value="Contact">
</form>
```

thank-you.php

```
<?php
    include_once('email.php');
    $firstname = '';
    if(isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    }
?>
<div class="message">Thank you for contacting - <?php echo $firstname;?></div>
```

email.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['contact'])) {
    $to = 'email@example.com';
    $subject = 'Contact';
    $message = 'Message';
    if(mail($to,$subject,$message)) {
        echo "mail sent";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, the thank you page just doesn't want to show anything from the php :(

Comment: You had included email.php in thank you page, so I am wondering what exactly you are trying to achieve..